# Specify format(s) of text copied from Qt app? Somehow crashes other app when pasted

Tags: python, qt, text, utf-8, pyside2

I'm making a small Qt/Pyside2/QML app whose entire purpose is to conveniently generate and copy some text for pasting into another program. (In case it matters, it's https://lackeyccg.com/; I suspect the only fact about it that may be relevant is that it's old enough that it doesn't play nicely with Unicode at all.) I'm currently running macOS 10.13, in case the particular clipboard is relevant.

In PySide, I copy text like so:

```py
clipboard = QGuiApplication.clipboard()
clipboard.setText(text_to_copy)
```

Calling `clipboard.mimeData().formats()` tells me that the data is formatted as `text/plain`. Switching to a text editor, web browser, etc. and pasting works just fine. Additionally, if I then select what I've pasted, copy *that*, and paste it into LackeyCCG, everything is again fine. Unfortunately, pasting directly into LackeyCCG after copying in Qt crashes Lackey.

I've verified this with several test strings, ruling out possible causes like non-ASCII characters or newlines; it seems the only thing that *doesn't* cause a crash is an empty string.

I'm guessing this has something to do with which text formats Qt provides. By running `osascript -e 'the clipboard as record' | less` on the command line, I can inspect the contents of the system clipboard. Text, when copied from several text editors, as well as from Chrome, contains the formats `<<class utf8>>`, `<<class ut16>>`, and `string`. (The `string` version has newlines replaced by carriage returns, oddly enough.) In contrast, the text copied from my Qt app contains `string`, `Unicode text`, and `<<class ut16>>` (and its `string` has ordinary newlines).

I don't have the firmest grasp on the particulars of text encodings, but it seems possible that the operative difference here is the lack of a UTF-8 version. Obviously most modern apps are smart enough to interpret what Qt gives them, even though it's different from what most apps apparently produce. But for those of us trying to paste into abandonware, is there a way to force Qt/PySide2 to output text in specific formats? (Or any insight on what the problem could be, if that's not it?)

Comment: Sounds tricky... the only thing I can help you with is that `^M` stands for the carriage return character (what you get for `\r` in Python strings). If you say that "special characters" are not discriminative, then my guess is that text encoding (UTF-8, UTF-16 etc.) is not the first thing to investigate, rather it's about the metadata that apparently is attached to the clipboard content. Maybe there are different protocols for these data – I have no idea how they are built.

Comment: @lenz: Thank you for the clarification; I've edited that part. I haven't been able to find any info on pasteboard metadata. According to writeups like this: https://eclecticlight.co/2020/05/12/cut-copy-paste-inside-the-pasteboard-clipboard/, it appears it just holds a collection of formats. I'd appreciate a link to more info, if you know of any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I still don't know if it's possible with PySide2's own mechanisms, I found a blindingly simple solution: https://pypi.org/project/pyperclip/

```py
import pyperclip
pyperclip.copy(text_to_copy)
```

The clipboard then contains a version in UTF-8 and everything works perfectly.